# Which is the best way to send Push Notifications in Android?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

Currently i am using onesignal.com push notifications. Is there any better service or better way to send push notifications in Android with more features?

Comment: Have you heard of FCM?

Answer (score 2):

You can use both GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) and FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging).
Some features of GCM are deprecated so Google is suggesting to use FCM.

FCM has a killing feature of sending notification to all users who have installed your app all or to those users who have subscribed to a particular topic(You can even check for topics i.e. Weather report for INDIA(who stays there),AUSTRALIA(who stays there).

You can implement FCM in your app very easily.
With FCM you can either use a Third Party Server or can send notification using their own cloud service.

Just visit and register your app with a coolest feature provided by Google-[FireBase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/).
You can even check some videos on Youtube-[Google Developer Videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1rlT5KQ0yE&list=PLRJ2BluHqh8JzP5xP6LKwfc8I704kPFnU)

Answer (score 0):

I use it with a lot of very nice handy feature [here](https://www.pushwoosh.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Firebase (https://firebase.google.com/). It's easy to learn and has good documentations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) to implement push notification. for better understanding go through [this](https://medium.com/@shaktisinh/android-push-notification-using-fcm-firebase-cloud-messaging-c37d165b8320#.i83zf9ojy) article